# Reurning an observable in an angular service

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following angular service

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class Xoom {
    get ct$(): Observable<IGroupSelectItem[]> {
        const ctBase$: Observable<IGroupSelectItem[]> = this.ctBase$
        const lowerLimb$: Observable<IGroupSelectItem[]> = this.lowerLimb$

        let result: IGroupSelectItem[]
        let result$: Observable<IGroupSelectItem[]>

        forkJoin([ctBase$, lowerLimb$])
            .pipe(
                tap(([base, limb]) => {
                    result = [...base, ...limb]
                    console.log(result)
                }),
            )
            .subscribe((ct) => {
                result$ = of(flatten(ct))
                console.log({ result })
            })
      console.log(this.ctResult)

        return result$  // error - variable assigned but never used
    }

}
```

The return statement runs before it is being initialize in the forkJoin subscription.

How can ensure that results$ is initialized before it is returned?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return statement runs before forkJoin subscription because the forkJoin is put on a [queue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) and will be executed later, after the current synchronous task. That's why it returns undefined because the forkJoin as not be executed at the moment of the return.

For you information, note that it's possible to execute observable synchronously with a [scheduler](https://rxjs.dev/guide/scheduler).

You are mixing together synchronous and asynchronous tasks. You should rely on the rxjs operators instead of using a local context when possible. Here I used [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) to stay in the reactive side of programming.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class Xoom {
    get ct$(): Observable<IGroupSelectItem[]> {
        const ctBase$: Observable<IGroupSelectItem[]> = this.ctBase$
        const lowerLimb$: Observable<IGroupSelectItem[]> = this.lowerLimb$

        return forkJoin([ctBase$, lowerLimb$])
            .pipe(
                map(([base, limb]) => {
                    return flatten([...base, ...limb]);
                }),
            )

    }

}
```

Then the consumer may do something like

```
xoomInstance.ct$.subscribe({
   next: (res) => {this.result = res;}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The return statement run before it is being initialize because forkJoin is asynchronous function; It's like you write this:

```
console.log('start');
setTimeout(() => {
   console.log('setTimeout');
}, 0);
console.log('end');
```

and result will be:

```
// start
// end
// setTimeout
```

because console.log('setTimeout'); was sent to a third party api and and executed after the main thread. You can read about it by searching "javascript event loop"

To resolve you problem you should work with `result` in `subscribe` like:

```
.subscribe((ct) => {
     result$ = of(flatten(ct))
     console.log({ result })
     return result$; //or something like that I don't know what your task is
})
```